# Display last record in erb Rails with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, will-paginate

I am trying to display the last instanced record from my model Tribune with this layout : 

Some random tribune 
Some random tribune

## Last

Last recorded tribune

I am using the gem will_paginate which allow me to display 10 tribunes / per page. 
The issue is that the layout is working but applied to each page. 
Every 10 tribunes, one is identified as "last". Obviously, I would like to have only one tribune identified as last.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="wrapping">


<% @tribunes.each do |tribune| %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mouse-out-container"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <% if tribune == @tribunes.last
%>
  <h1>Last</h1>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-category">Popular</div>
      <div class="card-description">
        <h2><%= tribune.title %></h2>
        <p><%= tribune.content.split[0...25].join(' ') %>...</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-user" src="https://kitt.lewagon.com/placeholder/users/tgenaitay">
      <%= link_to "", tribune, :class => "card-link" %>
    </div>
  <% else %>


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-category">Popular</div>
      <div class="card-description">
        <h2><%= tribune.title %></h2>
        <p><%= tribune.content.split[0...25].join(' ') %>...</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-user" src="https://kitt.lewagon.com/placeholder/users/tgenaitay">
      <%= link_to "", tribune, :class => "card-link" %>
    </div>

      </div>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="center-paginate">
      <%= will_paginate @tribunes, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When all Goole-fu fails, we have to dig in [the source code](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb). There we find some interesting methods:

> ```
> # Any will_paginate-compatible collection should have these methods:
> #   current_page, per_page, offset, total_entries, total_pages
> #
> # It can also define some of these optional methods:
> #   out_of_bounds?, previous_page, next_page
> ```

From these, the method `next_page` looks interesting, as it seems to return `nil` if there are no more pages.

Now we can construct the loop:

```
<% @tribunes.each do |tribune| %>
  <% if !@tribunes.next_page && tribune == @tribunes.last %>
     <!-- We're on the last page and the last tribune of that page -->
     Last tribune content
  <% else %>
     <!-- We still have tribunes to go -->
     Normal tribune content
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I will be happy to delete my answer in favor of this approach. :)